# PHP mail sending duplicates with different timestamp

Tags: php

I've got a PHP/AJAX form on my site at http://www.brianrhea.com (click Request Project)

When I test the form from multiple computers, it works fine for me. However, I will sporadically receive a duplicate e-mail and have heard from at least one user who tried to submit that it gave them an alert error which I am unable to duplicate.

This is the PHP that I'm using. Is there anything that stands out as a potential issue?

```
<?php

//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$subject = ($_GET['subject']) ?$_GET['subject'] : $_POST['subject'];
$comments = ($_GET['comments']) ?$_GET['comments'] : $_POST['comments'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.';
if (!$subject) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please choose a subject.'; 
if (!$comments) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your comments.'; 

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

    //recipient
    $to = 'brianrhea@gmail.com';    
    //sender
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'Comment from ' . $name; 
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Subject</td><td>' . $subject . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Comments</td><td>' . nl2br($comments) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
        else echo 'Please verify that you have entered a valid email address.';

    //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
    //ajax script can react accordingly
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;   
    }

//if the errors array has values
} else {
    //display the errors message
    for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
    echo '<a href="form.php">Back</a>';
    exit;
}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

?>
```

Comment: might be a little easier to use $_REQUEST: An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Comment: And FYI there is no validation on you $_GET/$_POST you should validate against user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does not appear to send the mail twice.

- Try to search for other places in your application where this code/functions maybe called from.
- Check also if you have a refresh prevention - if you detect ajax requests send very close in time with the same data, or against of some sort of double click usage.

Comment: Thanks Elzo, I'll check in to that. Are you able to submit the form successfully?

Comment: Indeed, there is a chance the event is being triggered more than once if the user is fast enough to click the button twice.

Comment: I realized what it is. The form data is not being cleared out after submission. So if the user refreshes the page for some reason it resubmits the form. I need to find a way to get the form inputs to clear after submission and then I think I'll be set. Thanks for the help!